# Make sure opened dropdown is visable in viewport

Tags: javascript, viewport

I have a react component which is a dropdown. Everytime the dropdown is opened I need to check if the whole dromdown is in the viewport/visible (specially for mobile devices)
If dropdown is cutoff by viewport need to scroll so the whole dropdown is visable (having said that the height of dorpdown varies).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {


    if (prevState.isOpen === false && this.state.isOpen === true) {
        if (this.node) {
            const optionContainer = this.node.querySelector(
                '.price-dropdown-options'
            );

            const recNode = this.node.getBoundingClientRect();
            const recOption = optionContainer.getBoundingClientRect();


            if ([some logic]) {
                //window.scrollBy(0, ?????); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: this.node is reference to dropdown button.Also the options section is positioned absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a built-in method for that called [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

It should be like:

```
dropDown.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I only need to scrollToTheView if the dropdown is outside of view port. How to detect that?

Comment: @NeginBasiri you mean outside of view entirely? What if half of the dropdown is inside viewport? Why not just call `scrollIntoView` everytime dropdown is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Font the answer.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {

    if (this.state.isOpen && this.state.isOpen !== prevState.isOpen) {
        const optionNode = this.node.querySelector('.price-dropdown-options');
        const buttonRec = this.node.getBoundingClientRect();
        const optionRec = optionNode.getBoundingClientRect();

        const height1 = buttonRec.top + buttonRec.height + optionRec.height;
        const height2 = window.innerHeight - 80; //80 is height of sticky footer

        if (height1 > height2) {
            scrollBy(0, Math.abs(height1 - height2));
        }
    }
}
```